# Shared format between HTML input type="date" and type="time"

Tags: javascript, c#, html, forms, json.net

I'm looking for a string format that represents a time that HTML5's input of `type="date"` and `type="time"` can share.

Currently, I'm serializing a C# object to JSON. This object has `DateTime` properties, representing either dates or times. When these properties are serialized, they're serialized to ISO 8601, an example being:

```
2021-01-01T01:43:00
```

However, to my surprise, this standardized date format does not work with both HTML5 inputs of types `date` and `time`.

Is there a shared date/time format between these two input types, so that I can serialize these date and time properties to the same format and apply them as values to the inputs of both types?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the HTML input element with the datetime-local type to allow users to input both date and time in a single input field. Here's an example:

```html
<input type="datetime-local" id="meetingDateTime" name="meetingDateTime">
```